# Why is there an "a" in "beggar"? Why not an "e"?

Tags: etymology, orthography

Why does *beggar* end in *-ar*? Many identically sounding words just use *-er*, if not all.

Examples:

1. bumper
2. pepper
3. tagger
4. chanter
5. pegger

They all use the *-er* version. Also, history shows that *beggar* was once spelled with an *-er*:  *begger*.

Why did *beggar* adopt *-ar* over *-er*, and why haven’t other words done the same thing?

Comment: Google ngrams shows that the spelling with an a was pretty much always more prevalent. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Begger%2CBeggar&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CBegger%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbegger%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBegger%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2CBeggar%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbeggar%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBeggar%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Though actually on closer inspection I think that this may not be reliable as the same books show up with both spellings. E.g. "Blind begger of Alexandria" and "Blind beggar of Alexandria" so maybe this includes "corrections" in modern versions.

Comment: It is pointless that the world evolved to a change from "begger" to "beggar" when the original was "begart". What is the advantage and how was this "ruled"?

Comment: Surely beggar is closer to begart? FWIW I don't pronounce pepper as rhyming with beggar. One is "er" as in ermintrude and the other "ar" as in "aromatic".

Comment: Not just about rhyming; about ending with "er". I just feel that not all words need to be changed over and over to different phonetic terms and written spellings that cause higher likelihood of mistakes.

Comment: English evolved though. It wasn't designed by some committee.

Comment: The language did not "evolve"; it was changed to reflect how different committees didn't like it and remains officially nor unofficially unchanged still.

Comment: @MartinSmith Are you really sure that you pronounce _begger_ and _pepper_ with a contrastively different final syllable? If so, you’re probably the first person I’ve ever come across that does so. The vowels in those two final syllables are slightly different, but that’s because they adapt to their preceding consonants: the /ə/ is retracted a bit after velar consonants, and fronted and raised a bit after bilabials. At the very least, _tagger_, _pegger_, _dogger_, _logger_, _bigger_, and _begger_ should all have the exact same final syllable; so too _bumper_, _paper_, _robber_, and _pepper_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So too do *actor, author, doctor* sound like *farmer, writer, thinker*, which is why children have such trouble spelling them.

Comment: I am very curious, in which dialect exactly do *pepper, bumper, chanter* and *beggar* sound identical?

Comment: @RegDwigнt We’re really just talking about the endings, which are always /ɚ/ however that works out in any given dialect. That’s how *booger, bugger, burglar, beggar, digger, pepper, bumper, chanter, cantor, canter, peddler, pedlar, paper, writer, rider, liar, dyer, vicar, flicker, scholar, dollar, molar* can be said to have “the same final syllable”. It’s at best a bit imprecise/inaccurate to say that, since with some of those one would attribute a consonant to the final syllable that is not present in others. So let’s just say they all end in /ɚ/ and leave it at that.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Only speaking for myself, but in my American dialect (northern Ohio), they all have the same "er" as "bird".

Comment: @tchrist: Except *exemplar*, from your list, can have a different pronunciation of the final syllable (and usually does).

Comment: Excuse me, from your *original* list. The answer has been through so many revisions I've lost track since yesterday.

Comment: @Robusto I exempted *exemplar* from the list I provided Reg for that very reason: because despite being spelled with final *‑ar*, it doesn’t end in /ɚ/ when said. That particular bucket also holds similarly high-falutin’ Latinate words like *registrar, cinnabar, epistolar, justiciar, seminar* but notably not Latinate *anular, calendar, lunar, molar, nectar, solar, stellar, tartar, Templar*, which do actually end in /ɚ/ by virtue of having been kicked around in our mouths longer. *Scimitar* and *vinegar* may not have been Latin, only Romance.

Comment: You should explain why you think *beggar* “should” be spelled *begger* with *‑er* instead of *‑ar*.  There are virtually infinitely many words ending in *‑ar* and *‑or* (not to mention *‑our* and sometimes *‑re*) that are also pronounced the same as the *‑er* words are today. Unless you explain what you meant, the same “reasoning” should produce *grammar > *grammer, solar > *soler, doctor > *docter, author > *auther, armour > *armer, glamour > *glammer, acre > *aker, fire > *fyer*.

Comment: @tchrist - I definitely pronounce "solar" (short "a" sound) with a different ending sound than "grammar" (classical "er" sound).  And the same goes, to varying degrees, for the other words in your list.  The differences are subtle, but the ear can definitely hear the difference.

Comment: @PoisonDart To the contrary, English *did* evolve. That "committees" have tried to influence its evolution at times doesn't eliminate the fact that [language naturally changes over time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_linguistics)...

Answer (score 44):

## Is it *-er*, *-ar*, or *-or*?

The first thing to understand about historical variation in modern *beggar* versus older *begger* is that the history of writing *‑ar, ‑er, ‑or* for English word-endings is rather complex and not a little muddled.   It is unwise to look for perfect predictability here.

In answer to your question about why other words didn’t do that, it turns out that some did. Like *beggar*, *liar* too started off with *‑er*, as did *pedlar*, and even today both *peddler* and *pedlar* continue to occur even though the *‑er* form is the elder.  Going the other way, Scots once had *socerar* for *sorcerer*, and you can still [find people who write *sorceror*](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22sorceror%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en).

It should be no great surprise that there would have been broad historical variation in spelling these sorts of words, considering how all three of  *‑er*, *‑ar*, *‑or* as unstressed final syllables are and were pronounced identically by most speakers.  Before spelling was regularized, whether a written word ended in *-er*, *‑ar*, or *‑or* was up to each individual writer’s preferences, and those in the north of the Isle of Britain often used *‑ar* here where *‑er* was more prevalent in the south.  A lot of the northern *‑ar* words later got reworked into *‑er* words, but not all of them.  And some, like *begger*, went the other way.

How that sorted itself out under regularized spelling, let alone readjusted spelling by those trying to toe a more Latinate line, did not always follow the same path for each word. The French also had some hand in this, since today’s *friar* is spelled that way because despite having been a *frater* in Latin, we got the word from *frere* in Old French (Modern French *frère*).

Although the normal agent-noun suffix in English is *‑er*, English also has a number of agent-nouns that derive from Latin now have *‑ar* there instead, such as *bursar, scholar, vicar*; *vulgar* and even *cellar* are also from Latin. But those only settled out that way due to spelling reform; most were originally  *‑er* words in English because of having come to us through the  French, who had changed Latin *-arius* words into *-(i)er* words.  Some of those instead ended up looking like *solitaire* in English.

Thanks in part to the invention of Old French which had only *‑(i)er* there, many of these words were once spelled with *‑er* before getting put “back into” *‑ar* form under 17<sup>th</sup>-century spelling reforms. And some — like *pedlar, liar,* and *beggar* — seem to have been dragged along for the ride more by analogy rather by etymology.

While these  *‑ar* words that we got from Latin (with or without French intervention) are in theory distinct from native English words ending in  *‑er* and from Latin  *‑or* words (mostly agent-nouns like *author, cantor, doctor, censor, cursor, elector, inventor, lictor*), this distinction was not always well-preserved:  notice how both *sorcerer* and *sorceror* occur, as do both *imposter* and *impostor*, with *sorcerer* and *impostor* now the more accepted or common renditions of those pairs.  Plus even though *‑er* was **usually** a native-English ending, Latin also contributed some *‑er* words of its own to English, like *neuter, integer, dexter, sinister, super*.

Because of how 17<sup>th</sup> century orthographers wanted to make words look more like Latin when writing them, eventually some of our words that were normally *‑er* even up north got reworked into *‑ar* words instead, consciously or unconsciously tying them to *‑ar* Latin forms whether real or imagined.

Examples already mentioned include *liar* and *pedlar*, but there are many more.  A lot of words had their standardized spellings changed into unhistorical forms during this time, famously including ones like *island* and *debt*. In [its article on English Spelling Reform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_spelling_reform#16th_and_17th_centuries), Wikipedia states:

> From the 16th century onward, English writers who were scholars of Greek and Latin literature tried to link English words to their Graeco-Latin counterparts. They did this by adding silent letters to make the real or imagined links more obvious. Thus *det* became *debt* (to link it to Latin *debitum*), *dout* became *doubt* (to link it to Latin *dubitare*), *sissors* became *scissors* and *sithe* became *scythe* (as they were wrongly thought to come from Latin *scindere*), *iland* became *island* (as it was wrongly thought to come from Latin *insula*), *ake* became *ache* (as it was wrongly thought to come from Greek *akhos*), and so forth.

As the last sentence cited above shows, mistakes **were** made during this time. And while it is arguable, *beggar* seems to have been one of these. The OED is not completely certain of this, as they say “probably imitating”. In particular, they say of *beggar*:

> The spelling in *-ar* has been occasional from 14th c., but the usual form in 15–17th c., as an ordinary agent-noun from *beg*, was *begger*: see **‑ar**<sup>3</sup>.

Which states:

> **‑ar**, *suff.*<sup>3</sup>, casual variant of *‑er, ‑or,* suffix of agent, and *‑er* suffix of comparative. Very common in north. dial., as *syngar* singer, *forebear* predecessor, *soutar* sutor; *hear* higher. And in modern Eng. in *beggar, liar, pedlar*. Probably imitating the refashioned *scholar, vicar, pillar* for earlier *scoler, viker, piler*: see **‑ar**<sup>1</sup>, and **‑ar**<sup>2</sup>, above.

The **‑ar**<sup>1</sup> case contains such words as *altar, collar, pillar, solar, lunar, regular, similar*, and so includes words that came to us both directly from Latin and via Norman French, and in English sometimes showed up as *‑(i)aire* as in *ordinaire* and which are related to the *‑ar*<sup>2</sup> case.

The **‑ar**<sup>2</sup> case is words we refashioned from Old French *‑ier*, but which ultimately have the same origin as *‑ar*<sup>1</sup> words.  These include words like *bursar, mortar, vicar*. Many of these used to be *‑er* words in English, but got redone in a “more Latin way” to turn them into their current *‑ar* forms.

The histories behind *‑er* and *‑or* words in English are both of them even more complex than those of *‑ar* are.

Comment: Note that the _-ar_ forms are derived from adjectives and are not primarily agent nouns: Latin never had _-ar_ as such: the ending is a blend of ① the highly productive adjective suffix _-ārius (-ārium)_, and ② the less prevalent, but still quite common, adjective suffix _-āris (-ārem)_, a dissimilated form of _-ālis (-ālem)_ for roots containing an l. Both just vaguely indicate ‘of the kind specified; relating to’, whereas the _-or_ nouns are straight from Latin and are truly agentive, even in Latin itself (and in PIE, where the main agentive suffix was _-tor_).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I’ve tried to fix that, since I was misstating that entire agent-noun issue from the Latin perspective.  *Cursors* and *actors* are different from something that was *similar* or, thanks to French, *solitaire* and *extraordinaire*.

Comment: Still, if the word comes originally from Middle Dutch *beggaert*, that implies that it *doesn't* originate with the English verb *to beg*, but that the verb was derived from the noun.

Comment: I would have stopped at the first paragraph if I were writing this. But nonetheless, this gets an upvote from me.

Comment: @Pitarou I think the problem is that the OP hasn’t expressed why he thinks *beggar* should be spelt as *begger*.  It probably was phonetic when we first got it, but as it got used more and more its final syllable fell to /ɚ/, so people started writing it that way. It’s like how *calendar* and *solar* now have /ɚ/ due to long use in the language, but *exemplar* and *seminar* do not (well, plus they’re stressed and therefore unreduced, but it’s all related).

Comment: I tend to think of "beggar" and "begger" as having slightly different meanings: a "beggar" is a person who begs for a living, while "begger" would be someone who was begging at a particular moment in time, though the latter would only be something of an ad hoc "verb-er" formation, appropriate only in contexts where other ad hoc "verb-er" formations would likewise be appropriate.

Comment: Sir or Madam, The article you wrote is so well written and contains so much information that I would like to add it to Wikipedia. May I have your permission to attempt to do so? I would have to rework it and add some material from the comments. I would also like to pass the completed article by you to ensure that I didn't accidentally ruin it.

Answer (score 17):

Well, the vagaries of English spelling are legendary. This is one of its more peculiar ones.

According to Etymonline.com,

> c.1200, from Old French *begart*, originally a member of the *Beghards*, lay brothers of mendicants in the Low Countries, from Middle Dutch *beggaert* "mendicant," of uncertain origin, with pejorative suffix (see -ard). Compare Beguine. Early folk etymology connected the English word with *bag*. Form with -ar attested from 14c., but *begger* was more usual 15c.-17c.

So it started off with the -ar, got turned around to -er, and went back again. There is no good reason for it, it just turned out that way.

Comment: I think it should go back to "begger". It makes no sense to go to "beggar" when the real original was "begart".

Comment: Who says it has to make sense? If there is one thing we can be sure of, it's that English spelling has very little "sense" to it.

Comment: I just can't stand it. People often mistake it for "begger" and others call them stupid. If it would have just stayed as "begger", feelings would be hurt less.

Comment: There was a movement during the 17th century to institute "etymologically correct" spellings. This is when the 'b' was restored to *debt* (whose origin was Latin *debitum*, but it had been pronounced without a 'b' since before English borrowed the word from Old French in the 14th century). I expect the 'a' was restored to *beggar* for the same reason.

Comment: @PeterShor Whether it was in intentional imitation of Latin *-ar* words or was simply giving way to northern tendencies where *-ar* was often preferred is something that is probably forever lost in the mists of times.

Comment: I might choose 'begger of questions' over 'beggar of questions', but I'd probably rephrase. Choosers can have 'beggers'.

Comment: *Beg* as a verb is an uncouth neologism, though. It's not that "someone who begs is a beggar", but that some idiot in the past decided that someone who is a beggar must, by some extension, be engaged in begging. It's rather like someone saying that a motor motes.

Comment: @bye Hey, even I'm not that anti-neologistic. And I'll probably start using 'mote' where the register would not be too unsuitable.

Comment: @bye What “uncouth neologism” do you purport for the verb *beg*?  Middle English had “Scheome ich telle uorte··beggen ase on harlot··his liueneð.” in the early 1200s, and Old English in the late 800s had “Hit is swiðe wel be ðæm ʒecweden ðæt he eft bedeciʒe on sumera, & him mon ðonne noht ne sell.”

Comment: @tchrist Agreed completely with your point (though not necessarily with your last quote—it’s not really certain whether _beg_ is the continuation of _bedecian_ or not, after all). If we start referring to words that appeared almost a millennium ago as “uncouth neologisms”, we’ll have to come up with a whole spectrum of new words to describe words that can actually still be considered ‘new’ (such as _neologism_, for example, which is somewhere around 600 years ‘newer’ than _beg_ as a verb).

Comment: I think we can only go back to ME for *beg* as a verb; the OE citation is peculiar, and nothing occurs between it and many centuries later.

Comment: @tchrist - I didn't say *when* it was coined, just that it's not formed from a regular action/actor relationship. (It would have been about the same time as *uncouth*, *rude* and *homely* all meant more-or-less the same thing.)

Comment: @bye Here is a [long, horrifying list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_back-formations) of "uncouth neologisms", including such abominations as "edit", "swindle", and "pea". Yuck!

Answer (score 5):

Willard Van Orman Quine, the great polymath, on this topic (Quiddities, p115-116):

> Examples [of historical relics in English that can reward contemplation] are evident at every turn. Let me cite one of the less evident ones: the ending *-ar* in *beggar*, *burglar* and *pedlar*. In our words of Old English origin the usual ending for agent is *-er*, and in words borrowed from Latin it is *-or*; what then of this deviant *-ar*? Looking up origins, we find that historically *beggar*, *burglar* and *pedlar* are not even formed from verbs; there was no question of an agent ending. The three nouns came first, from other sources. Afterward we derived the verbs *beg*, *burgle* and *peddle* from them by "back-formation", subtracting the *-ar* as if it had been an agent ending.

Comment: Middle English had a verb *beg* in the early 1200s: “Scheome ich telle uorte··beggen ase on harlot··his liueneð.”  If *beg* is a back-formation, it is an extremely old one. One can find the verb *beguigner* in French starting from the 1300s. This is likely why the OED says of *to beg* that “Perhaps the most likely derivation is from the OF. *begart, begard,* and *begar*, med.L. *begardus* = Beghard, or its synonym *beguin,* beguin, **and deriv. vb. *beguigner, beguiner*** ‘to act the *beguin.’”*

Answer (score 5):

@Robusto has the answer, however, to magnify a little, beggar is probably not, as we might assume, derived from the verb "to beg" as with many of the other examples you give. On the contrary, the verb is derived from the noun. So normal formation would not be expected. Also from Etymonline:

> [beg](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=beg&searchmode=none) c.1200, perhaps from Old English bedecian "to beg," from
>   Proto-Germanic *beth-; or possibly from Anglo-French begger, from Old
>   French begart (see beggar). The Old English word for "beg" was
>   wædlian, from wædl "poverty."...

A parallel might be helpful. We have the word "burglar" as someone who breaks in an steals. In the UK the verb that is used for this action is "to burgle" -- as in "my house was burgled." However, in the USA they generally use "to burglarize", as in "my house was burglarized."

The difference derives from the fact the the original word is the noun, and the verbs are back formed from it using two different methods of back formation.

The history of the word is pretty interesting.

> [burglar](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=burglar&searchmode=none) 1540s, shortened from Anglo-Latin burglator (late 13c.),
>   earlier burgator, from Medieval Latin burgator "burglar," from burgare
>   "to break open, commit burglary," from Latin burgus "fortress,
>   castle," a Germanic loan-word akin to borough. The intrusive -l- is
>   perhaps from influence of Latin latro "thief" (see larceny). The
>   native word, Old English burgh-breche, might have influenced the word.